# Why does it say that no module named pygame was found when I try to import turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Basically, i'm trying to use the turtle module at home as I have been using it in school and it's quite fun to use. However, when I try to import it and run the code, it says that there is an error in line 1 of the code and says that no module named pygame was found. I didn't write pygame, I  specifically wrote

```
from turtle import *
```

which at school works perfectly fine. Both my computer and the school computers use Python 3.6 but the turtle module will just not work at home. Any ideas why this might be happening? If it helps, I've tried to install pygame in the past but it wouldn't work so I stopped trying to install it, and just now I tried deleting and uninstalling pygame but it still shows up with the error. Thanks for taking your time to read my question.

**The error that comes up is as follows:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/homeuser/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/jsjs.py", line 1, in <module>
    from turtle import *
  File "C:/Users/homeuser/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32\turtle.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
>>>
```

Also, pip install pygame comes up with an error saying invalid syntax

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include your error when you try to import turtle?

Comment: try `pip install pygame` in your terminal/cmd prompt then re-run. Let us know what happens

Comment: Please post the full error traceback!

Comment: I have now I hope it is of use to you

Comment: That line should not exist in turtle.py. You may have accidentally edited or replaced the file. (You really shouldn't edit Python's standard library.)

Comment: Looking at where your `jsjs.py` file is, yup, you've been working inside a Python standard library directory and clobbering important files. Your Python installation may be severely messed up by now. I recommend a clean reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

- First, you need to download the version of pygame suitable for your version of python. Here's a link to their download page: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pygame/1.9.3
- Next, open the command prompt. This technique works provided that you have pip installed and you have the required environmental variables.
- Now, type in the following into the command prompt: 'python -m pip install "Path/To/Downloaded/File.py"'
- Here's a real-life example: 'python -m pip install "C:/Users/danie/Downloads/pygame-1.9.3-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl"'

If you have any errors, it would most likely because:
- (A) You don't have pip installed properly.
- (B) You gave an invalid directory branch.
- (C) You spelled something in the command wrong.
- (D) You forgot to download the Pygame module.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Pygame should be a dependency of turtle. Try to download pygame with pip.

More information about the installation:

https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted

Answer (score 0):

You've been working inside a Python standard library directory, placing your own files there and clobbering Python's insides. The error you're seeing is because you've edited or replaced the `turtle.py` from the standard library. At this point, there's no telling how much damage has occurred, and manually fixing things isn't going to be practical.

Uninstall and reinstall Python to restore things to normal, and stop putting your own work in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing the error code you've posted, it seems that some files placed in the python directory have been messed with or there must have been some changes. Nevertheless, You can try doing an uninstall and then doing a clean install of python. 
Then proceed to download pygame by:

```
pip install pygame
```

and then **turtle** module. You may have to look up for the Tkinter module too.